# tcp connection from webpage to android app

Tags: php, android, ip, tcp

Wanted to make a TCP/IP chat interface between the TCP/IP socket sporting app on my Android and similar TCP/IP implication in PHp on the webpage where my website is hosted.
I have previously formed TCP/IP app which is able to talk with my computer (where another java tcp server is loaded) but now I want to talk to my webpage, is it that simple to just make the client on my Android have the same IP address of my website and a specific port?

basically I'm trying to make a webpage that connects to the app on my android and sends some information on click of a button on the webpage, How to got about it?

Comment: I believe you should reword your question, for me it is unclear what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Basically I want to have a button on the webpage that when I click sends a char/byte to my Android device over TCP/IP Socket connection

Comment: assuming you know how to set your Android device to listen to a specific port, you could use an AJAX event bound on the button's click, to query a php file on your server that eventually uses php's fsockopen() and fwrite() to send your character to your android device. Is that what you need? If so I can provide an answer with some code.

Comment: Yes this is what I need, thanks, but also can this communication be two ways? like click on button on Android sends a char to webpage?, Will this be TCP/IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for taking too long to answer, I didn't have the chance to work much in the previous days.

Assuming you haven't already found your answer and you have your android device configured to listen to a specific port, you can use the following method.

Your (very basic) html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
        <head>
                <title>Chat</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="contact.js" ></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="my_text">
                </form>
                <button id="send">Send!</button>
        </body>
</html>
```

Your contact.js file:

```
$(function(){
        $('#send').click(function(){
                var your_text = $('#my_text').html();
                send_to_droid(your_text);
        });
})

function send_to_droid(your_text){
        $.ajax({
                url: "send_to_droid.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                        "your_text": your_text
                }
        })
}
```

And finally, you send_to_droid.php file:

```
<?php
    $handle = fsockopen(<android device's ip>,<android device's port>);
    fwrite( $handle , $_GET['your_text'] );
?>
```

I did not take much time to test this and certainly you can implement it way way better to manage failed connections etc, but I hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks! and at the Android part I just need to establish a TCP/IP compliant app that listen's on a specific port?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.